# PHP DateTime Class Producing Unexpected Results

Tags: php, datetime, var-dump

I have been getting used to the DateTime Class and am getting unexpected results from the code below:

```
<?php  
  $now =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  echo $now .'</br>';
  $newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("$now + 1 years"));
  $converted = strtotime("$newDate");
  $outputDate = new DateTime("@$converted");
  var_dump($outputDate);
  echo "Output - ". $outputDate->date;
?>
```

When I have the `var_dump($outputDate)` I get the expected output (i.e. the Output string is at the end):

```
2015-03-29 23:08:30
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-03-29 21:08:30.000000"   
["timezone_type"]=> int(1) 
["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" } Output - 2016-03-29 21:08:30.000000
```

However when I have the exact same code and comment out `var_dump($outputDate)`:

```
<?php  
  $now =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  echo $now .'</br>';
  $newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("$now + 1 years"));
  $converted = strtotime("$newDate");
  $outputDate = new DateTime("@$converted");
  // var_dump($outputDate);
  echo "Output - ". $outputDate->date;
?>
```

I just get:

```
2015-03-29 23:14:13
Output -
```

I am not sure why having the `var_dump($outputDate)` line allows me to output the date. I have resolved the issue using a different approach but I am curious to why this is the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have already written an answer with explanation *why* it happens. Cannot post it since the Q is closed already. Anyway: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L2163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` property is not defined in [Datetime class docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) so this behavior is **undefined** and you can't rely on such code. For getting your datetime represented as string you should use `format()` method like this:

```
echo "Output - ". $outputDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//or with procedural style
echo "Output - ". date_format($outputDate,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

You can read more about possible `format` parameters on [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: @underflow - hope this helped you. Can you accept answer in closed-as-duplicate question?

Comment: Oh, as i can see - you can :)

Comment: yes I can, I couldn't immediately as had to wait a certain time. Now to figure out why DateTime takes hours away from the original date

Comment: Also - you shouldn't rely on your `$converted` value. Try to construct your `DateTime` object, ad then use `modify()` method which can increment your date by `+1 years` http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php